# Which browser control does electron use to create a custom browser?

Tags: user-interface, browser, electron

I want to create a custom browser using electron. I am new to electron and want to know that which browser control does electron use (chrome, IE, etc)?

Comment: Electron uses the Chromium rendering engine to render but I am unsure what you mean by "browser control".

Comment: Thanks for answering! I wanted to ask about the backend library used by electron.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great resources on the web that will answer your question. Use your favourite search engine to find out more.

That said, at a basic level [What is Electron?](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest#what-is-electron) will get you started.

Essentially, Electron is built upon:

- The Chromium rendering engine. (The rendering engine used by Google Chrome)
- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- A whole bunch of C++ scripts (among others)

If is an open source project which can be viewed at https://github.com/electron/electron.

Poke around in the source code if you want a deeper understanding of how it is put together / works.